# Retrieve the data from SQL database into Window Phone Silverlight application C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, navigation, database-connection

I develop an application to search the nearby workshop base on my current location and use Bingmap AOSP to route and bring user into nearby workshop.I stuck to retrieve data from database that i created.Please help.I want to retrieve data from database and show on one of the page.Database created using sql server 2008.How should insert the connection string and where should insert?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use direct connection with a sql-server database.

Use a wcf-webservice instead. [Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196996/Consuming-WCF-Service-from-Windows-7-Phone-Applica) a tutorial to accomplish this.

Comment: I follow the tutorial and i get Custom tool warning when i add the WCF service reference to my application. Spend several hour still unable to solve. Already follow the tutorial to done but still having same problem.

Comment: You'd best create a new question here on Stackoverflow for this specific problem. I'm not familiar with Custom tool warnings.

Comment: Beside than using WCF..any other method?